# Cmake doesn't find boost windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost, cmake, deep-learning

I'm trying to run this code:
https://github.com/snukky/news-translit-nmt

I've installed boost and got the following messages:

```
The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

    C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_67_0

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

    C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_67_0\stage\lib
```

By the comment of @kenba I've added the following environment variables:

[image: env-vars]

#### Try 1

When I try to run the following cmd:

```
 cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

I get:

```
-- Could NOT find Boost (missing: timer iostreams filesystem system chrono) (found version "1.67.0")
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:290 (message):
  Cannot find Boost libraries.  Terminating.


-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/ThesisResources/previous_works/news-translit-nmt-master/tools/marian-dev/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

#### Try 2

When I try to give a custom boost by this ref
https://marian-nmt.github.io/docs/#custom-boost:

I run the following cmd:

```
 cmake .. -DBOOST_ROOT="C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_67_0"
```

I get the same error.

- I've also tried working with Linux WSL (But problems with CUDA installation overthere, their team is working on it), Linux VirtualBox (Not enough resources), and Ubuntu 17.10 I have installed (But Cuda requires Ubuntu 16.04 / 18.04)

What am I missing here? I'm trying any suggestion, stuck on it for a few days. Thanks!

Edit:
I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 and the problem was solved. Still don't know how to solve it in windows, but i'll continue use Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You need to set the `BOOST_ROOT` and `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` environment variables so that `cmake` can find the `boost` header and library files.

Comment: @kenba please see post edit. I've tried what you suggest and it doesn't seem to resolve my problem

Comment: Your `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` is incorrect for `cmake`. It should be `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_67_0\stage` not `C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_67_0\stage\lib`

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 and the problem was solved. Still don't know how to solve it in windows, but i'll continue use Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem earlier while trying to build the Windows version of Marian NMT (the same component that you're having trouble with). I can't remember the exact steps to solve the problem, but the root cause is that the Marian NMT build for Windows does not work with newer versions of Boost, since the source code uses some deprecated calling conventions for timer and chrono libraries (maybe some others as well).

The error message kind of confirms this: it can't find Boost, but on the other hand it says it finds your version 1.67.0. The solution is to use an older version of boost, I've confirmed that it works with 1.60.0.

If you just require a Marian NMT decoder that works in Windows, a project I work on has released a plugin for the Trados Studio translation tool, which contains a compiled marian-decoder executable for Windows: https://object.pouta.csc.fi/fiskmo/TradosStudio/FiskmoTranslationProvider.sdlplugin. You can access the executable by unzipping the sdlplugin file, the StartMtPipe.bat shows how to use the decoder.